# Preserve ls colouring after grep'ing

Tags: bash, grep, colors, ls

If I do

```
$ ls -l --color=always
```

I get a list of files inside the directory with some nice colouring for different file types etc..

Now, I want to be able to pipe the coloured output of `ls` through `grep` to filter out some files I don't need. The key is that I still want to preserve the colouring after the grep filter.

```
$ ls -l --color=always | grep -E some_regex
```

^ I lose the colouring after grep

EDIT: I'm using headless-server Ubuntu 8.10, Bash 3.2.39, pretty much a stock install with no fancy configs

Comment: FWIW it works for me. It could have something to do with the terminal emulator you're using.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your grep is probably removing `ls`'s color codes because it has its own coloring turned on.

You "could" do this:

```
ls -l --color=always | grep --color=never pattern
```

However, it is very important that you understand what exactly you're `grep`ping here.  Not only is `grep`ping `ls` unnecessary (use a `glob` instead), this particular case is `grep`ping through not only filenames and file stats, but also through the color codes added by `ls`!

The real answer to your question is: Don't `grep` it.  There is never a need to pipe `ls` into anything or capture its output.  `ls` is only intended for human interpretation (eg. to *look* at in an *interactive* shell only, and for this purpose it is extremely handy, of course).  As mentioned before, you can filter what files `ls` enumerates by using globs:

```
ls -l *.txt      # Show all files with filenames ending with `.txt'.
ls -l !(foo).txt # Show all files with filenames that end on `.txt' but aren't `foo.txt'. (This requires `shopt -s extglob` to be on, you can put it in ~/.bashrc)
```

I **highly** recommend you read these two excellent documents on the matter:

- Explanation of the badness of parsing `ls`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs
- The power of `glob`s: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: As usual, shell coding on higher (and sane) levels. ++

Comment: @lhunath I never realized how bad such practice could be, thanks for the links and although I was using some advanced regex I will try and migrate that to glob and use natively inside `ls`

Comment: thanks for opening my eyes to this.  I usually run "find" and see what comes up before I pipe the results to xargs <something>

Comment: @orange80: Don't pipe find(1) output to xargs(1).  xargs is a broken tool since it tries to be "clever" and breaks your input filenames where there's whitespace and quotes.  Nobody should ever use xargs (except for the rare case where you're using -0, which has almost always better alternatives).  Instead, just use find's -exec command {} +.  It does exactly the same thing as xargs, except, it doesn't rape your filenames (and you don't have the pipe + extra parsing  + extra processes overhead).

Comment: Nice. AFAIK is not possible to use glob for filtering symlinks like in this example: `ls -l --color=always /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep --color=never sda`

Comment: @A.D. You _can_ filter symlinks with zsh glob patterns! `ls *(@)` lists all symlinks, and `ls *(^@)` lists all non-symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you are really using the "real" ls, just by directly calling the binary:

```
/bin/ls ....
```

Because: The code you described really should work, unless ls ignores --color=always for some weird reason or bug.

I suspect some alias or function that adds (directly or through a variable) some options. Double-check that this isn't the case.