# Preserve colouring after piping grep to grep

Tags: linux, bash, colors, grep, pipe

There is a simlar question in [Preserve ls colouring after grep’ing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867877/preserve-ls-colouring-after-greping) but it annoys me that if you pipe colored grep output into another grep that the coloring is not preserved.

As an example `grep --color WORD * | grep -v AVOID` does not keep the color of the first output. But for me `ls | grep FILE` do keep the color, why the difference ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix command usage, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: One way I've been dealing with this is to circumvent/work around the problem whenever possible. That is, avoiding piping to grep is sometimes doable. We can use `grep fobar $(find . -name \*.json)` instead of `find . -name \*.json | xargs grep fobar` for example.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

`grep` sometimes disables the color output, for example when writing to a pipe. You can override this behavior with `grep --color=always`

The correct command line would be

```
grep --color=always WORD * | grep -v AVOID
```

This is pretty verbose, alternatively you can just add the line

```
alias cgrep="grep --color=always"
```

to your `.bashrc` for example and use `cgrep` as the colored grep. When redefining `grep` you might run into trouble with scripts which rely on specific output of `grep` and don't like ascii escape code.

Comment: This solution only works under certain lucky circumstances. See andersonvom's answer below.

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu) I had already alias to `grep`. `alias grep='grep --color=auto` so I need to just alter my `~/.bashrc` where it was defined in the first place.

Comment: Not working for me - similar to this scenario https://stackoverflow.com/a/7640077/248616

Comment: This nice creative idea is just simple and working https://stackoverflow.com/a/36288791/248616

Comment: the question is about how to make the second grep not supress the color of the first one. This is not an answer to that.

Comment: This does not work in this example: `git log -1 | grep --color=always -C 5 'Date'`
all colors are lost

Answer (score 84):

A word of advice:

When using `grep --color=always`, the actual strings being passed on to the next pipe will be changed. This can lead to the following situation:

```
$ grep --color=always -e '1' * | grep -ve '12'
11
12
13
```

Even though the option `-ve '12'` should exclude the middle line, it will not because there are color characters between `1` and `2`.

Comment: If you use `--color=auto`, then it should pick up the fact you're piping it somewhere else and suppress colors altogether, but it kind of defeats the purpose.  If you still want colored results, I guess you could grep it again at the last pipe using `--color`.

Comment: On Mac OS X, at least, coloring at the last pipe as @andersonvom suggests does not work. Not sure why; maybe it's coloring the excluded pattern? `--color=always` does work, with, I assume, the caveats stated above.

Comment: You have to have the same grep pattern twice in your expression.  I just tested this on a mac: [http://i.imgur.com/BhmwAlF.png](http://i.imgur.com/BhmwAlF.png)

Comment: The easiest but least informative answer I can give is that you should do all of your exclusions earlier in the pipeline and finish with a positive match, ideally a union of all the patterns you want highlighted so it does so in a single step. As an aside, I believe you will also run into matches with the escape codes/sequences themselves, I don't see why you wouldn't. `\e[38;5;155m 12 14 16 18 \e[m` should match `15`. I'm not good enough with Grep to tell you if it's possible to match "15 but not between `\e[` or help with the "12" split by formatting.

Comment: Oh, when formatting is added, won't the ith character become the (i+n)th with formatting? (N is the number of escape code characters by the ith original character.) Then you have correspondence, as long as you can identify the escape codes (`\e[...m`?). You can find the start and end of a match in a raw line, then find the corresponding point of each in the formatted line. E.g. `11 12 13` has "12" from 3-5 which is 3-17 in `11 1\e[38;5;155m2\e[39m 13`, or 3-20 depending. Then bold it yourself: `11 \e[1m1\e[38;5;155m2\e[39m\e[2m 13` (which moves the correspondence to 9-23.)

Answer (score 31):

The existing answers only address the case when the FIRST command is `grep` (as asked by the OP, but this problem arises in other situations too).

## More general answer

The basic problem is that the command BEFORE `| grep`, tries to be "smart" by disabling color when it realizes the output is going to a pipe. This is usually what you want so that ANSI escape codes don't interfere with your downstream program.

But if you want colorized output emanating from earlier commands, you need to force color codes to be produced regardless of the output sink. The forcing mechanism is program-specific.

### Git: use -c color.status=always

```
git -c color.status=always status | grep -v .DS_Store
```

Note: the `-c` option must come BEFORE the subcommand `status`.

### Others

(this is a community wiki post so feel free to add yours)

Comment: Some Git commands also have their own `--color=always` option, as in: `git branch --color=always | grep --color=never -v foo`

Answer (score 13):

Simply repeat the same grep command at the end of your pipe.
`grep WORD * | grep -v AVOID | grep -v AVOID2 | grep WORD`

Comment: Wouldn't reversing the commands provide the same result? `grep -v AVOID * | grep WORD`

Comment: @BrydonGibson probably, but it was  an example to show that it works for any number of piped commands

Comment: Had to append `--color=always` to the last command for this to work for me.  (The first command producing color was `git grep`.) And I'll add that `grep -v`'ing my entire codebase would seem rather excessive...

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/537631 - you can exclude and include within the same pattern. I don't really know if `grep -P` is okay for you. I believe your command would be something like `grep -P
'(?=^((?!AVOID).|^(?!AVOID2).)*$)WORD'`. According to the user, it'll "quit" (move on) early if it meets an excluded pattern. I couldn't get it to match WORD more than once though. I'm not a Perl guy and I'm bad with Grep to begin with.