# How to check for only high vulnerabilities when using "npm audit"?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-audit

When you I execute `npm install` using new **npm 6**
i got a messages that tell me I have some **vulnerabilities** :

> [!] 75 vulnerabilities found [4867 packages audited]
>
> Severity: 66 Low | 4 Moderate | 5 High
>
> Run `npm audit` for more detail

I ran `npm audit` but got a truncated list of vulnerabilities.

How I can check for only **High** vulnerabilities list ?

Thanks

Comment: reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities

Answer (score 55):

Not the answer you are looking for, but it will do the same:

```
npm audit | grep -B 1 -A 10 High
```

Comment: Thank you, But as you said it's not what I'm looking for, Some `High` vulns has a recommendations and this solution omits them.
There must be a `param` to `audit` to filter results or at least display them page by page

Comment: Meanwhile you can try tweaking the `grep` parameters. I think `-B 2` should include the recommendations.

Comment: Use `npm audit --json` to show transitive dependencies also instead of just top level dependencies according to ChatGPT / GPT4.

Answer (score 46):

This one worked for me:

**Show High Only**

```
npm audit | grep -E "(High)" -B3 -A10
```

**Show both Critical and High Issues**

```
npm audit | grep -E "(High | Critical)" -B3 -A10
```

Look at the [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20596) discussion where this solution is proposed.

Comment: on NPM -v 8.18 use `npm audit | grep -E "high" -B3 -A10` or just `"critical"` instead.

Answer (score 39):

If your are looking to do it in Powershell, just use the following command (Adapted from @stayingcool's answer):

**Show High Only**

```
npm audit | Select-String -Pattern "High" -Context 0,10
```

**Show both High and Critical**

```
npm audit | Select-String -Pattern "(High | Critical)" -Context 0,10
```

Answer (score 8):

***Edit:** I recommend this (better) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58056454/88111*

It's not as pretty, but you can do:

```
npm audit --parseable | grep high
```

With one additional downside being any package/issue metadata containing `"high"` will also be printed.

Comment: Works only if `grep` is available, like in *nix system.

Comment: `npm audit` doesn't seem to have a `--parseable` option.

Answer (score 2):

The `--audit-level=high` flag doesn't change the output of npm audit.

I'm sending this to html for reporting purposes, so looking to clean it up further:

```
npm audit | grep -E "(High | Critical)" -B3 -A11 --color=always | grep -E '┌|│|├|└' --color=never
```

But this will lose the title, and the 'found vulnerabilities' at the bottom. I found it simplest to just run npm audit a couple times and get the bits I need appended to a file.

Ended up going with something like this:

```
npm audit | grep '===' --color=never > temp.txt
npm audit | grep -E "(High | Critical)" -B3 -A11 --color=never | grep -E '┌|│|├|└' --color=never >> temp.txt
npm audit | grep -E "(found|scanned packages)" --color=never >> temp.txt
cat temp.txt
```

Or as a catchy one liner (lol) that also removes the temp.txt file:

```
npm audit | grep '=== npm audit' --color=never > temp.txt; npm audit | grep -E "(High | Critical)" -B3 -A11 --color=never | grep -E '┌|│|├|└' --color=never >> temp.txt; npm audit | grep -E "(found|scanned packages)" --color=never >> temp.txt; cat temp.txt; rm temp.txt;
```

The line is ugly but is working well across a bunch of different repos, provided you only need the output in the terminal.

When outputting to a file, npm audit includes ansi color codes, that can't be turned off. And this is a problem for my reports! Sed can be used to remove them:

```
sed -i '' $'s,\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g' temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to count the High(s):

```
npm audit | grep 'High' | wc -l | rev
```

Comment: This seems not to be needed, since `npm install` already lists this overview at the end (and in colour! ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Put this line into your audit scripts:

```
"audit": "level=$(npm audit --parseable | grep -E 'high|critical' | wc -l | rev); [ $level == 0 ] && exit 0"
```

This code does check the output of `npm audit`. If there are no high or critical vulnerabilities the process will not exit with error.

Comment: Improved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To amalgamate a few other answers, the following works well enough for me around npm audit's output format changes, as tested for npm v6, v8 and v10 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 and npm v10 on Windows 11 with [Git Bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win):

```
npm audit --color=always | grep -i -E "(high|critical)" -B2 -A10
```

With thanks to the following posters:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/why-is-the-terminal-case-sensitive
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63456696/1101109
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58056454/1101109

Answer (score -2):

This package might be what you are looking for:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/audit-filter

It lets you filter by advisory number, which is better than filtering by level.

```
$ cat .nsprc
{
  "exceptions": [
    "https://npmjs.com/advisories/532",
    "https://npmjs.com/advisories/577"
   ]
}
```

Couple that with [npm config for audit level](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#audit-level) and you're golden.